# django Page not found (404) forms

Tags: python, django

i'm building a  simple app using django and i got this error when i'm making an authentication

here is the error
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http: / /localhost:8000/POST?csrfmiddlewaretoken=AZSGUVU7Z13xZoSOsuvFrSPDGy1ZXfHjeJtpHW3HCByK4We0fyLTihcIJsUKUKjt&username=a2020&password1=123456&password2=123456

here is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login



    def home(request):
        return render(request,'home.html')
    
    def signup(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
    
        return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form})
```

here is urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    
    path('',views.home,name="home"),
    path('signup',views.signup,name="signup")
]
```

signup.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content%}
<div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-6 is-offset-3">
            <h1 class="title">Sign up</h1>
            <form action="POST">
                {%csrf_token%}
                {{form.as_p}}
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-success">
                            sign up
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

Comment: show your `signup.html`

Comment: You need to set `method="post"` on your `<form>` tag in your template

Comment: i made an error it should be method not action ...